# Unable to convert string to URL in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, urlcomponents

In order to make HTTP request call using URLSession,I need to convert string to URL first so I have tried everything but just can’t convert this piece of string to URL(string: ).
This is the string:
“http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99”

I can’t share the exact Url but format is all same.
The actual url with same format works fine in browser but no way in Swift, also that works fine in POSTMAN
I have also tried URLComponents which hepls me create the URL from components to URL but that fails with 400 status code response error.
I really appreciate the help, I am completely bogged down with this isuue and can’t proceed with my assignment.

**Update:** Tested with fiddler and request was not going through with this URL -  "“http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99”"

But when removed this %E2%80%8B in fiddler and resend it worked.
Any thoughts ..?

Comment: Have you tried addingPercentEncoding or urlHostAlloqed or urlQuery allowed?

Comment: If you don't print your api response all you can do is guessing. `print(Data(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")`

Comment: `URL(string: "http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99")` seems to create an URL without trouble. Do you have an example of a URL that actually fails?

Comment: I tried addingPercentEncoding with URLQuery, fragments and other ytpes but nothing worked, and when create URL using URLComponents it adds some special characters next to  http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com

Comment: Check your POSTMAN headers configuration. Are you doing a post or a get?

Comment: What special characters does it add next to the host? When I try `URLComponents(string: "http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99")`, it creates an URLComponents without trouble. Can you post code that demonstrates your problem? (You can't just call `addingPercentEncoding` to random parts of a String. It generally is not the right tool unless you know precisely what you're doing.)

Comment: @LeoDabus I am doing Get and used the Swift code snippet given by postman but that also crashes where URL is forming

Comment: Are you saying that it is returning `nil` from `URL(string:)` initializer?

Comment: What happen when you compose your string using `URLComponents`?

Comment: @RobNapier when I use print(urlComponents.url?.absoluteString)
it shows this "http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99"

Comment: special characters added by `URLComponents` shouldn't be an issue

Comment: That looks like you called `addingPercentEncoding` blindly on the string. Don't do that. See Euan Traynor's answer for an example of how to use URLComponents. (But I expect the problem is in the specific URL you're trying to encode. You need to show us something that actually fails. I expect your string is just not a legal URL in the first place.)

Comment: @LeoDabus but in that case request fails with 400 status response but show json response when used in browser

Comment: As already stated by Rob make sure to pass the string to URLComponents without any percent encoding

Comment: @RobNapier but what makes it run fine in safari

Comment: @gagansharma it doesnt mean anything. Safari does what you are not doing under the hood.

Comment: @LeoDabus I am using URLComponents without any percent encoding

Comment: Show your code, how you construct the URL, even if you obfuscate some keys, base URL, etc. But at least try to keep "special characters" if there is... Like `http://myURL.com/path1/path2/query?key1=value_1&key2=value2`, etc.

Comment: As Leo notes, the Safari address bar accepts a wide variety of strings that are not valid URLs. It has various ad hoc rules for deciding what to do with those strings. The string "example.com" is not a valid URL (it has no scheme), but if you type it into the Safari address bar, it will turn it into `http://example.com` and navigate to it. On the other hand, if I type just "example" (also not an URL), it will convert that to an URL for a web search. You cannot use the Safari address bar to determine if something is an URL.

Comment: If you cannot show us the specific string that fails, you need to show us *some* string that fails in a similar way. If you just say "I send a string to URL and it doesn't work," the answer is "that string isn't a valid URL." We can't help you beyond that without an example. You can read the rules at [RFC 3986 section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3)

Comment: @RobNapier Please see my updated findings in question.

Comment: "But when removed this %E2%80%8B in fiddler and resend it worked." Yes, because that's not part of a valid HTTP URL. When you connected to a host that didn't exist, it failed. When you edited the URL to connect to a host that does exist, it works. Where did you get this string from?

Answer (score 1):

**String to URL**

```
let url = URL(string: "the url string goes here")
```

**URL to String**

```
let url = URL(string: "the url string goes here")
let urlString = url.absoluteString
```

**Creating URL from URLComponents**

```
var url: URL? {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "domain goes here" //example: twitter.com
    components.path = "/path/goes/here"
    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "item1", value: string1),
        URLQueryItem(name: "item2", value: string2)
    ]

    return components.url
}
```

Comment: OP have already tried using URLComponents

Comment: @LeoDabus It's not clear that the OP has used URLComponents correctly, however (and very likely has not). Demonstrating its use is very helpful.

Comment: I am already using the same way but it adds %E2%80%8B symbols in Url, then fail

Comment: You have an invisible character in your URL string. %E2%80%8B refers to the character "Zero Width Space" (Code point: U+200B). Try manually retyping in the URL string completely from scratch... or use the following method. `extension Character { static let zeroWidthSpace = Self(.init(0x200B)!) var isZeroWidthSpace: Bool { self == .zeroWidthSpace } }` and `extension Bool { var negated: Bool { !self }}` and finally call it `let filteredStringURL = str.filter(\.isZeroWidthSpace.negated)`

Answer (score 0):

try to add HEADER to you request:

```
let url = URL(string : urlString)
var request = URLRequest(url : url)
request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField : "Content-Type")
```

Comment: this is irrelevant if OP is not posting anything

Comment: Correct setValue will have no effect here.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is:

```
http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99`
```

The "host" portion is:

```
api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B
```

`%E2%80%8B` encodes a [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). This is a perfectly valid URL:

```
URL(string: "http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99")
=> Optional(http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99)
```

However, there is no such host as `api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B`, so you should expect the actual connection to fail.

I expect that whatever is generating your URL strings has a bug.

If you are having trouble creating the URL itself (if `URL(string:)` return nil, then I expect this is not your actual URL string.

If you construct an URLComponents, the results are correct but may be slightly misleading:

```
URLComponents(string: "http://api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com%E2%80%8B/v1/car-types/manufacturer?page=0&pageSize=10&wa_key=abc-cde-efg-44ccd99")?.host
Optional("api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com")
```

While this looks like `"api-aws-eu-qa-1.abc-cde.com"`, the string actually has a ZERO WIDTH SPACE at the end, which is invisible (but still part of the host field, which will correctly fail if you try to connect to it).